# How do I clear the resource cache in Wicket?

Tags: caching, localization, wicket

In my Wicket application I use StringResourceLoaders for my text resources.
Text keys and values are loaded from a property file and a database.

I have created a service class for storing and fetching the text resources, and here I also have a scheduled task that updates the text resources once every 15 minutes.

When this task executes I first update the text resources and after that I want to clear the resource cache to make Wicket use the updated texts.

My problem is that the cache is not cleared. Here's how I try to do it...

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=15*60*1000) // 15 minutes
private void taskUpdateTextResources() {
    updateTextResources();
    Application.get().getResourceSettings().getPropertiesFactory().clearCache();
}
```

This obviously is not the correct way to clear the resources, but then how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

To periodically invalidate the resource cache you can set the ResourcePollFrequency.

Add this to your application's init method and all resources should be repolled every 15 minutes.

```
getResourceSettings().setResourcePollFrequency(Duration.minutes(15));
```

Comment: Thanks! Though it wasn't the scheduling part of the application that was broken, I will consider using this method for executing taskUpdateTextResources.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now solved. I found out that Application.get() returned null (quite embarrassing).

I had to add the Application as a member variable.

Here's the solution:

```
@Inject
Application application;


@Scheduled(fixedDelay=15*60*1000) // 15 minutes
private void taskUpdateTextResources() {
    updateTextResources();
    application.getResourceSettings().getPropertiesFactory().clearCache();
}
```